# 'Node' : use of class template requires template argument list

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, templates

I am making a BST tree traversal, and I get an error when I use a template for it.
Thank You!
Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template<typename T> struct Node{
     T data;
    Node*left;
    Node*right;
};

template<class T>void PreOrder(Node* root){
    if (root == NULL) return;
    cout << root->data;
    PreOrder(root -> right);
    PreOrder(root -> left);
}
```

And I always get an error saying "Node' : use of class template requires template argument list. "
Thank You in advance for help.

Comment: did you mean: `template<class T>void PreOrder(Node<T>* root){` ?

Comment: Btw, it should be `const`.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the **`Node<T>`** syntax (instead of just `Node`) also in the `PreOrder()` function signature:

```
template<class T> void PreOrder(Node<T>* root) {
```

This code compiles fine with MSVC10:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T> struct Node {
    T data;
    Node*left;
    Node*right;
};

template<class T>void PreOrder(Node<T>* root) {
    if (root == NULL) return;
    cout << root->data;
    PreOrder(root->right);
    PreOrder(root->left);
}

int main() {
}
```